# Specifying a custom (Realdict) cursor for queries using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, database-cursor

Can we specify a different cursor when executing queries via SQLAlchemy.
I want to be able to use `Realdict` cursor (as mentioned in this article: http://alexharvey.eu/database/postgresql/postgresql-query-result-as-python-dictionary/) with SQLAlchemy

This is a sample code of how the query is executed:

```
with connection:
             result = connection.execute(select(columns_to_select).where(clause))
             row = result.fetchone()
```